# How to convert S3 bucket content(.csv format) into a dataframe in AWS Lambda

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am trying to ingest S3 data(csv file) to RDS(MSSQL) through lambda. Sample code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
     if event:
        file_obj = event["Records"][0]
        bucketname = str(file_obj["s3"]["bucket"]["name"])
        csv_filename = unquote_plus(str(file_obj["s3"]["object"]["key"]))
        print("Filename: ", csv_filename)
        csv_fileObj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=csv_filename)
        file_content = csv_fileObj["Body"].read().decode("utf-8").split()
```

I have tried put my csv contents into a list but didnt work.

```
 results = []
        for row in csv.DictReader(file_content):
         results.append(row.values())
        print(results)
        print(file_content)
        return {
           'statusCode': 200,
           'body': json.dumps('S3 file processed')
         }
```

Is there anyway I could convert "`file_content`" into a dataframe in Lambda? I have multiple columns to load.

Later I would follow this approach to load the data into RDS

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
# insert data from csv file into dataframe(df).
server = 'yourservername' 
database = 'AdventureWorks' 
username = 'username' 
password = 'yourpassword' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
# Insert Dataframe into SQL Server:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
     cursor.execute("INSERT INTO HumanResources.DepartmentTest (DepartmentID,Name,GroupName) values(?,?,?)", row.DepartmentID, row.Name, row.GroupName)
cnxn.commit()
cursor.close()
```

Can anyone suggest how to go about it?

Comment: **Side-note:** Your code is only processing the first record sent to the Lambda function (`event["Records"][0]`). It is possible that multiple event records can be sent to the Lambda function, so your code should loop through and process each Record.

Comment: What is the contents of the object in S3?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein, its a csv file. File size 12mb

Comment: Why do you particularly want to use Dataframes? The AWS Lambda function can read the CSV file directly and generate the SQL commands.

Comment: I tried creating a list but didnt work. updated my question above. Hence, tried creating a dataframe. could you pls suggest anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `io.BytesIO` to get the bytes data into memory and after that use pandas`read_csv` to transform it into a dataframe. Note that there is some strange SSL download limit for dataframes that will lead to issue when downloading data > 2GB. That is why I have used this chunking in the code below.

```py
import io
obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucketname, Key=csv_filename)
# This should prevent the 2GB download limit from a python ssl internal
chunks = (chunk for chunk in obj["Body"].iter_chunks(chunk_size=1024**3))
data = io.BytesIO(b"".join(chunks)) # This keeps everything fully in memory
df = pd.read_csv(data) # here you can provide also some necessary args and kwargs
```

Comment: Hi @simon, I tried your solution above. but i m getting an error saying " [ERROR] MemoryError" in this line "data = io.BytesIO(b"".join(chunks))". my csv file size is just 12mb

Comment: It worked. I had to increase lambda function memory..

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your goal is to **load the contents of a CSV file from Amazon S3 into SQL Server**.

You could do this without using Dataframes:

- Loop through the Event Records (multiple can be passed-in)
- For each object:

  - Download the object to `/tmp/`
  - Use the Python `CSVReader` to loop through the contents of the file
  - Generate `INSERT` statements to insert the data into the SQL Server table

You might also consider using [aws-data-wrangler: Pandas on AWS](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler), which is available as a Lambda Layer.

Comment: Hi @John, yes my goal is to load contents of a CSV file from Amazon S3 into RDS MSSQL Server. i am unable to perform 2 steps mentioned above.  not sure how to do it though!. could u pls assist. this is something new for me.

Comment: You are welcome to create a new Question, show your code and provide details of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Problem got fixed. i am able to load s3 contents into RDS..